# serverless slsw.lib.entries is always empty

Tags: javascript, webpack, serverless

I'm trying to deploy to Lambda using serverless. In my webpack.config.js I have the following entry:

```
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack')
module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  ...
}
```

in my serverless.yml I declare the function as following:

```
functions:
  importUsersFromS3:
    handler: handlers.handler
```

and handlers.js looks like this:

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
  awaitcaptureAsyncFunc('handleSplitSpreadsheet', () => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
    log('event', { event })
    processLargeSpreadsheet(event, context)
  })
}
```

when I run `serverless webpack --out dist --stage dev --region us-east-1` I get the following error:

```
Webpack Options Validation Error -----------------------

  WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
   - configuration.entry should be an non-empty object.
     -> Multiple entry bundles are created. The key is the chunk name. The value can be a string or an array.
      at webpack (/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:31:9)
      at ServerlessWebpack.compile (/src/lambda/usersApi/node_modules/serverless-webpack/lib/compile.js:12:22)
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.invoke (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:464:22)
      at PluginManager.spawn (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:484:17)
      at ServerlessWebpack.BbPromise.bind.then.then (/src/lambda/usersApi/node_modules/serverless-webpack/index.js:150:51)
      at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
      at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my folder structure was like this

```
app
├── lambda
|   ├── usersApi
|   |   ├── handlers.js
|   |   ├── serverless.yml
|   |   └── package.json
|   ├── severalServiceFolders
|   └── webpack.config.js
└── package.json
```

In `app/lambda/usersApi/package.json` I had these devDependencies:

```
"serverless-plugin-aws-alerts": "1.2.4",
"serverless-plugin-tracing": "^2.0.0",
"serverless-webpack": "^5.3.1"
```

turns out removing them made the error go away.

only reference to `serverless` in root `package.json` is `"serverless-webpack": "^5.3.1"`